# Using nested loops in bash to process huge datasets

Tags: bash, julia, data-science

I am currently working on big datasets (typically 10 Gb for each) that prevent me from using R (RStudio) and dealing with data frames as I used to.

In order to deal with a restricted amount of memory (and CPU power), I've tried Julia and Bash (Shell Script) to process those files.

My question is the following: I've concatenated my files (I have more or less 1 million individual files merged into one big file) and I would like to process those big files in this way: Let's say that I have something like:

```
id,latitude,longitude,value
18,1,2,100
18,1,2,200
23,3,5,132
23,3,5,144
23,3,5,150
```

I would like to process my file saying that for id = 18, compute the max (200), the min (100) or some other propreties then go to next id and do the same. I guess some sort of nested loop in bash would work but I'm having issues doing it in an elegant way, the answers found on the Internet so far were not really helping. I cannot process it in Julia because it's too big/heavy, that's why I'm looking for answers mostly in bash.

However, I wanted to do this because I thought it would be faster to process a huge file rather than open a file, calculate, close file and go to the next one again and again. I'm not sure at all though !

Finally, which one would be better to use? Julia or Bash? Or something else?

Thank you !

Comment: Is the file sorted by ID? Otherwise you are going to fill your ram while processing using darned near any tool.

Comment: @JNevill Yes it is. For each ID, I have several observations of two variables,  producing such big files. Would you then suggest to do it file per file to let the ram survive? What's the pros and cons of doing this?

Comment: My thought was tossing `awk` at it and performing the min/max for each ID in there. If it wasn't sorted though, then that would be a monster.

Comment: How complex are your computations? Computing the min and max are easy to do in C or even C++ if you are really tight on memory.

Comment: @JNevill So `awk` can grasp information based on identical field, i.e. for each ID? @ssemilla, it's very basic computations such as computing the difference between min and max value for each ID. I though Julia could handle this since it is supposed to be a good alternative to C in scientific computing..

Comment: @Robert `awk` could do that. An array could be used pretty effectively here, but I would worry about the size. I think just grabbing the info into variables that are reset on each new `id` encountered would keep the footprint pretty low while processing in awk. Something like `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=",";minval="";maxval=""} id!=$1&&NR>2{print id, minval, maxval; id=$1; minval=""; maxval=""} $4<minval || minval==""{minval=$4} $4>maxva||maxval==""{maxval=$4} NR==2{id=$1}END{print id,minval,maxval}' inputfile` I'm certain that could be cleaned up but it would do the job.

Comment: I'd be interested to see how something like [this](http://harelba.github.io/q/) would do with it as well. `q  -H "SELECT id, min(value), max(value) FROM ./yourfile.csv"` I'm betting there would be some memory issues there though.

Comment: would be interesting to have a CPU time comparison between the datamash solution and a pure julia solution.

Comment: @PicaudVincent If you post an answer with a julia solution I would be glad to compare it to datamash. I already compared datamash to `q ...` as suggested by JNevill. I generated a 750M file. Datamash took 14s. I aborted `q` after 4 minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Julia or Bash?

If you are talking about using plain bash and not some commands that could be executed in any other shell, then the answer is obviously Julia. Plain bash is magnitudes slower than Julia.

However, I would recommend to use an existing tool instead of writing your own.

GNU datamash could be what you need. You can call it from bash or any other shell.

> for id = 18, compute the max (200), the min (100) [...] then go to next id and do the same

With datamash you could use the following bash command

```
< input.csv datamash -Ht, -g 1 min 4 max 4
```

Which would print

```
GroupBy(id),min(value),max(value)
18,100,200
23,132,150
```

Comment: Why not use `datamash -t,` instead of `tr`?

Comment: @mickp Thank you for the hint. At the time of writing I couldn't find the correct switch which lead me to believe there was none.

Answer (score 0):

Loops in bash are slow, I think that Julia is a much better fit in this case. Here is what I would do:

1. (Ideally) convert your data into a binary format, like NetCDF or HDF5.
2. load a chunk of data (e.g. 100 000 rows, not all, unless all data holds into RAM) and perform min/max per id as you propose
3. go to the next chunk and update the min/max for every ids

Do not load all the data at once in memory if you can avoid it. For computing easy statistics like the minimum, maximum, sum, mean, standard deviation, ... this can by done.

In my opinion, the memory overhead of julia (versus bash) are probably quite small given the size of the problem.

Be sure to read the performance tips in Julia and in particular place hoot-loops inside functions and not in global scope.
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html

Alternatively, such operations can also be done with specific queries in a SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, I'd be wary of using `bash`, because it isn't suited to line-by-line processing. And `awk` is too line-oriented for this kind of job, making the code complicated.

Something like this in `perl` might do the job, with a loop of loops grouping lines together by their `id` field.

```
IT070137 ~/tmp $ cat foo.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my ($id, $latitude, $longitude, $value) = read_data();
while (defined($id)) {
    my $group_id = $id;
    my $min = $value;
    my $max = $value;
    ($id, $latitude, $longitude, $value) = read_data();

    while (defined($id) && $id eq $group_id) {
        if ($value < $min) {
            $min = $value;
        }
        if ($value > $max) {
            $max = $value;
        }
        ($id, $latitude, $longitude, $value) = read_data();
    }

    print $group_id, " ", $min, " ", $max, "\n";
}

sub read_data {
    my $line = <>;
    if (!defined($line)) {
        return (undef, undef, undef, undef);
    }
    chomp($line);
    my ($id, $latitude, $longitude, $value) = split(/,/, $line);
    return ($id, $latitude, $longitude, $value);
}
IT070137 ~/tmp $ cat foo.txt
id,latitude,longitude,value
18,1,2,100
18,1,2,200
23,3,5,132
23,3,5,144
23,3,5,150
IT070137 ~/tmp $ perl -w foo.pl foo.txt
id value value
18 100 200
23 132 150
```

Or if you prefer Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt

from __future__ import print_function

import fileinput


def main():
    data = fileinput.input()

    (id, lattitude, longitude, value) = read(data)
    while id:
        group_id = id
        min = value
        (id, lattitude, longitude, value) = read(data)

        while id and group_id == id:
            if value < min:
                min = value
            (id, lattitude, longitude, value) = read(data)

        print(group_id, min)


def read(data):
    line = data.readline()

    if line == '':
        return (None, None, None, None)

    line = line.rstrip()
    (id, lattitude, longitude, value) = line.split(',')
    return (id, lattitude, longitude, value)


main()
```

Comment: I'd second perl, or some other number-crunching language with which you are reasonably comfortable. *I* prefer perl, but you might be more familiar with python, or php, or even (shudder) java. Use what works for you. As a rule, I use bash until I need to handle really large streams fast, or really large and/or complex memory structures, and/or a lot of fiddly math. Then I tend to fall back to perl of python.

Comment: Wise words. I used Perl for this example, because it is just easier for simple file mangling like this. But my colleagues code in Python, so I would have coded it in Python for work

Comment: I prefer Perl but would do it in python at the office because it's a python-ish shop. :)

Comment: Actually, I take that back. This looks nice in Python! I've added an example :-)

Answer (score 0):

Bash is definitely not the best option.  (Fortran, baby!)

Anyway, the following can be translated to any language you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

function postprocess(){
     # Do whatever statistics you want on the arrays.
     echo "id: $last_id"
     echo "lats: ${lat[@]}"
     echo "lons: ${lon[@]}"
     echo "vals: ${val[@]}"
}

# Set dummy start variable
last_id="not a valid id"
count=0

while read line; do
  id=$( echo $line | cut -d, -f1 )

  # Ignore first line
  [ "$id" == "id" ] && continue

  # If this is a new id, post-process the old one
  if [ $id -ne $last_id -a $count -ne 0 ] 2> /dev/null; then
     # Do post processing of data
     postprocess

     # Reset counter
     count=0

     # Reset value arrays
     unset lat
     unset lon
     unset val
  fi

  # Increment counter
  (( count++ ))

  # Set last_id
  last_id=$id

  # Get values into arrays
  lat+=($( echo $line | cut -d, -f2 ))
  lon+=($( echo $line | cut -d, -f3 ))
  val+=($( echo $line | cut -d, -f4 ))

done < test.txt

[ $count -gt 0 ] && postprocess
```